# runtime table @updated is not accessible after one use

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having an error on `@updated.id1` as it has been already declared above and if I want `output deleted.tblId` equal to `@coun` then how to achieve it?

```
alter procedure dbo.sp_updateAndUndoQryForsubmitOrder   --  sp_updateAndUndoQryForsubmitOrder 1,1
(
    @id int,
    @for nvarchar(50)=null,
    @coun nvarchar(50)=''
)
as
begin
    DECLARE @Updated table( id1 int);
        if(@for is not null)
            begin
                update tbl_orderDetails set curStatus='depo' 
                output deleted.tblId
                into @Updated
                where id=@id
                --Update the GroupName_old with old values
                update tbl_orders
                set curstatus='Ready'
                where (
                select count(*)
                from tbl_orderDetails as a
                inner join @Updated as b
                on a.tblId=b.id1
                where a.curStatus != 'depo' or a.curStatus is null)=0 and tbl_orders.oid=@updated.id1
                update tbl_order_execution set dep_date=GETDATE() where tbl_orderDetId=@Updated.id1

            end
        else
            update tbl_orderDetails set curStatus='pro' 
            output deleted.tblId
            where id=@id 
            --Update the GroupName_old with old values
            update a
            set curStatus='0'
            from tbl_orders as a
            inner join @Updated as b
            on a.oid=b.id1;
            update tbl_order_execution set dep_date = NULL;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
update tbl_order_execution set dep_date=GETDATE() where tbl_orderDetId=@Updated.id1
```

has a syntax error.  Should be something like

```
update tbl_order_execution 
set dep_date=GETDATE() 
where tbl_orderDetId in (select id1 from @Updated)
```

Amd further down this

```
        update tbl_orderDetails set curStatus='pro' 
        output deleted.tblId
        where id=@id
```

should probably be

```
        update tbl_orderDetails set curStatus='pro' 
        output deleted.tblId into @updated
        where id=@id
```

This would all be more readable if you put `;` and a blank line after each statement.

Comment: can you further tell me that can we store output "deleted.tblId" into a runtime variable like "@coun"

Comment: You cannout OUTPUT into a  scalar variable.  Only a table variable., The OUTPUT may have multiple rows. This was allowed for SELECT @Variabl=Column and caused no end of trouble.